# SQL : Getting Incorrect Syntax near '=' While using CASE statement with variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to perform the below query where some variables are being used. This below SQL code is a part of a stored procedure. Idea is to dynamically set the target columns and its values based on `FileKey`.

```
DECLARE @TargetColNames nvarchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @SourceColNames nvarchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @SourceColNamesInsert nvarchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @UpdateColumns nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN @FileKey IN ('s_1','s_2') 
            THEN @TargetColNames = @TargetColNames + ' [CreatedUser], [UpdatedUser], [CreatedDateTime],[UpdatedDateTime],[IsDeleted],[DeletedOn]'     
            ELSE @TargetColNames = @TargetColNames + ' [CreatedUser], [UpdatedUser], [CreatedDateTime], [UpdatedDateTime]' 
    END,
    @SourceColNames = CONCAT('CreatedUser','UpdatedUser','CreatedDateTime', 'UpdatedDateTime'),
    @SourceColNamesInsert = CONCAT(''',@User, ''',''',@User, ''', 'Getdate()', 'Getdate()' ),
    CASE 
        WHEN @FileKey IN ('s_1','s_2') 
            THEN @UpdateColumns = CONCAT('Target.UpdatedUser= ''',@User,''', 'Target.[IsDeleted]=0','Target.[DeletedOn]=null')
            ELSE @UpdateColumns = CONCAT('Target.UpdatedUser= ''',@User,''', 'Target.UpdatedDateTime=Getdate()')
    END
```

The above SQL statement throws an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure uspDynamicStageToPropLayer1, Line 165 [Batch Start Line 5]
> Incorrect syntax near '='.

What am I missing here? Maybe this is quite a silly mistake...

Comment: CASE is an expression - not a control-of-flow statement like in many other languages. You will need to use something like `@x = case .when ... then ... else ... end` to assign a single value to a single variable. I'll note you posted a fragment of a query - there is no FROM clause.

Comment: @SMor: Got the clue. Thanks! Besides, you actully don't need  `FROM` clause as we are setting some variables here.

Comment: Then use SET which is expressly implemented for setting variables rather than SELECT. Someone with your level of experience should be aware of how to write clear and readable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, by doing *concat* with your quoted parts, you might allow [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) into your query even building dynamically.  What if a user's name (or forced parameter *has* a leading single quote, then garbage injection such as

```
@User = ';drop table X --
```

Having said that, some of the stuff could be more simplified, such as

```
SELECT
   @TargetColNames = @TargetColNames
       + ' [CreatedUser], [UpdatedUser], [CreatedDateTime], [UpdatedDateTime]'
       + CASE WHEN @FileKey IN ('s_1','s_2')
              THEN ', [IsDeleted], [DeletedOn]'
              else ''
         end
```

For the insert, you will probably get a failure.  If you look at a possible result of the @User

```
@SourceColNamesInsert = concat(''',@User, ''',''',@User, ''',
'Getdate()', 'Getdate()' ),
```

will result with the value below which is *not* what I think is intended.  Notice no comma's between values because the triple ' is creating start and end literals, and leaves no actual comma between column insert values.

```
',@User, '',@User, 'Getdate()Getdate()
```

But instead...

```
select concat('''@User'', ''@User''', ', Getdate(), Getdate()' );
```

which will result in...

```
'@User', '@User', Getdate(), Getdate()
```

The ''' actually creates an opening quoted string immediately with the value after it, then the '' (double) closes the quoted string, but it also adds the comma separator before the next '' (double) to start second user and ''' (triple) to close the second @User, *then* adding comma and both getdate() calls.

```
'@User', '@User', Getdate(), Getdate()
```

Now, if the value for @User was 'Bob', and your intent was to have the string output as

```
'Bob', 'Bob', Getdate(), Getdate()
```

change to
select concat('''', @User, ''', ','''', @User, '''', ', Getdate(), Getdate()' );

The '''' (quad) means I want to open a string, do a single quote (by the inner two ''), and close this as its own string.  *then* get the *value* of the @User.  Then follow by an open string ' with '' for closing the quote around the name, then open a single quote to start the next, the comma before starting the next quote for the second user and closing it as well via '''', then the *value* of the user again, and finally closing the second user with close quote ''''.  Finally adding a comma and getdate() calls.  Yes, stupid tricky in the quoting.

An easier implementation without CONCAT() is just using + between each explicit part such as

```
select '''' + @User + '''' + ', ' + '''' + @User + '''' + ', Getdate(), getdate()' ;
```

where each '''' is a single quote thus resulting in

```
' + Bob + ' + , + ' + Bob + ' + , Getdate(), getdate()
```

resulting in

```
'Bob', 'Bob', Getdate(), getdate()
```

I'll leave the final UpdateColumns to you to confirm your intended output.

But, as mentioned, *beware of possible SQL injection* when you are dynamically building SQL statements with embedded parameter values as this *appears* to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to approach this:

```
Declare @FileKey                varchar(10) = 's_3'
      , @TargetColNames         nvarchar(max) = ''
      , @SourceColNames         nvarchar(max) = ''
      , @SourceColNamesInsert   nvarchar(max) = ''
      , @UpdateColumns          nvarchar(max) = '';

    Set @TargetColNames = concat_ws(', ', '[CreatedUser]', '[UpdatedUser]', '[CreatedDateTime]', '[UpdatedDateTime]');

     If @FileKey In ('s_1', 's_2')
        Set @TargetColNames = concat_ws(', ', @TargetColNames, '[UpdatedDateTime]', '[IsDeleted]', '[DeletedOn]');

  Print @TargetColNames;

    Set @SourceColNames = concat_ws(', ', '[CreatedUser]', '[UpdatedUser]', '[CreatedDateTime]', '[UpdatedDateTime]');
    Set @SourceColNamesInsert = concat_ws(', ', quotename('@User', char(39)), quotename('Getdate()', char(39)), quotename('Getdate()', char(39)));

  Print @SourceColNames;
  Print @SourceColNamesInsert;
```